# Android: Inflate One Class Into Another

Tags: android, class, tabactivity, tabwidget, android-inflate

I am creating a TabActivity menu to use throughout my application. Is there a way to build the menu in one class, and then inflate it into each activity I want to use it in?

The activity I want to inflate the tab menu into:

```
    private void setupView() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)RecipeGrainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    RecipeTabs tabs = new RecipeTabs(this, 1);
    View tabView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recipe_tabs, null);
}
```

The TabAcitity xml layout that I have already inflated into the main activity:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
> android:layout_width="fill_parent"
> android:layout_height="fill_parent">
> <LinearLayout
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:padding="5dp">
>     <TabWidget
>         android:id="@android:id/tabs"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
>     <FrameLayout
>         android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>         android:padding="5dp" />
> </LinearLayout> </TabHost>
> ```

The TabActivity class I have created to set up all my tabs:

```
public class RecipeTabs extends TabActivity {

private Context myContext;
private int currentTab;

public RecipeTabs(Context context, int currentTab) {
    this.myContext = context;
    this.currentTab = currentTab;
    Resources res = getResources();
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;

    //Grain Tab
    intent = new Intent().setClass(context, RecipeGrainActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("grain").setIndicator("Grain", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.grain_icon_states))
    .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    //Hops Tab
    intent = new Intent().setClass(context, RecipeGrainActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("hops").setIndicator("Hops", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.hops_icon_states))
    .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    //Mash Tab
    intent = new Intent().setClass(context, RecipeGrainActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("mash").setIndicator("Mash", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.mash_icon_states))
    .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    //Notes Tab
    intent = new Intent().setClass(context, RecipeGrainActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("notes").setIndicator("Notes", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.notes_icon_states))
    .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(currentTab);
}
```

}

When I try to run the activity I get the following error in the LogCat:

> 07-16 15:41:18.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
>   07-16 15:41:18.247: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bluelightuniverse.android.brewmobile/com.bluelightuniverse.android.brewmobile.RecipeGrainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   07-16 15:41:18.247: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2401)
>   07-16 15:41:18.247: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
>   07-16 15:41:18.247: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
>   07-16 15:41:18.247: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
>   07-16 15:41:18.247: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   07-16 15:41:18.247: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   07-16 15:41:18.247: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
>   07-16 15:41:18.247: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   07-16 15:41:18.247: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   07-16 15:41:18.247: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
>   07-16 15:41:18.247: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
>   07-16 15:41:18.247: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   07-16 15:41:18.247: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 07-16 15:41:18.247:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:80)
>   07-16 15:41:18.247: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at
>   com.bluelightuniverse.android.brewmobile.RecipeTabs.(RecipeTabs.java:17)
>   07-16 15:41:18.247: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at
>   com.bluelightuniverse.android.brewmobile.RecipeGrainActivity.setupView(RecipeGrainActivity.java:20)
>   07-16 15:41:18.247: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at
>   com.bluelightuniverse.android.brewmobile.RecipeGrainActivity.onCreate(RecipeGrainActivity.java:15)
>   07-16 15:41:18.247: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
>   07-16 15:41:18.247: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)

It's telling me I have an issue with the following line in the TabActivity class:

```
Resources res = getResources();
```

Which is i'm sure, the first of many errors it would detect because I don't think I am "inflating" the class correctly into the activity in order to set up the tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was overthinking this (as usual). I ended up setting the TabActivity as the main activity rather than trying to set it as a subclass. TabHost loads your "linked" activities automatically and its very easy to implement. Other resources to look up are Fragments as it follows the same principle and from the looks of it can be very useful in applications.